# iterate through a geoJSON file to create a dropdown menu

Tags: php, loops, foreach, geojson

Hi guys im new to php so weould really appreicate the help. i have a geoJSON file with all countries in the format below. i am trying to create a select (dropdown menu) populated by the info from this file.

im obviously doing osmething wrong as i wish to iterate through an array within an array but not sure how to do that. ideally i want to extract the country name and iso code for my drop down menu.

many thanks for all your help in advance.

so far i have manged:

```
<?php 

//to get data from file
$data = file_get_contents("countryBorders.geo.json");

//convert json object to an array for iteration - not sure if this is necessary
$arr_of_countries = (array)$data;


foreach ($arr_of_countries[0].features as $key => $value) {
     echo"".$key."".$value."";
 }
?>
```

the data in the json file is as follows for each country

```
Array ( [0] => {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"name":"Bahamas","iso_a2":"BS","iso_a3":"BHS","iso_n3":"044"},"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-77.53466,23.75975],[-77.78,23.71],[-78.03405,24.28615],[-78.40848,24.57564],[-78.19087,25.2103],[-77.89,25.17],[-77.54,24.34],[-77.53466,23.75975]]],[[[-77.82,26.58],[-78.91,26.42],[-78.98,26.79],[-78.51,26.87],[-77.85,26.84],[-77.82,26.58]]],[[[-77,26.59],[-77.17255,25.87918],[-77.35641,26.00735],[-77.34,26.53],[-77.78802,26.92516],[-77.79,27.04],[-77,26.59]]]]}},
```

Comment: Your code never runs `json_decode` so you won't end up with a proper array or object (based on the JSON data) to work with. Simply casting the JSON string to an array, as you're doing now makes no sense - PHP doesn't know it's JSON unless you tell it (by running json_decode), so (as your sample output shows) all you get from the cast is a string wrapped inside a single array element, which is clearly no use. Read the duplicate for a comprehensive guide to decoding JSON data and then using that data.

Comment: Please show a sample of the file

Comment: @pippo see the end of the post

Comment: @ADyson the posted example looks like a piece from a print_r. I would like to see how the file is composed

Comment: @Pippo true, but see my first comment - we can infer from the code that it's just the result of casting the string to an array, so the content of the original file is what's inside the array index. And why do you need to know anyway? The question is closed. There's very little to add beyond what's in the duplicate. OP clearly did zero research into how to deal with JSON in php or else they'd have easily learned they need to start off by using json_decode, and then go from there

Comment: Hi thanks everyone. adding JSON_decode worked.